# About marginal cost setting on Jordi Gali's work

Tags: macroeconomics, new-keynesian-economics, marginal

I'm studying Gali's work with the paper(or book?) which is
"Jordi Gali, Monetary policy inflation and the business cycle_An introduction to the new keynesian framework(2015)" and wonder one thing about setting marginal cost of a firm.

On the paper chapter 3 THE BASIC KEYNESIAN MODEL, with respect to the behavioral principal of firms, he suggests **an individual firm’s marginal cost in terms of the economy’s average real marginal cost** as
[image]

but I cannnot understand why the first equality works since I have been teached that w/p=mpn in general.

Anybody who let me know the solution idea to solve it??

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please type equations using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/70119).

Comment: Please define what the variables are.

Answer (score 2):

The equation is in logs. Thus,
$$MC_{t}=\frac{W_{t}/P_{t}}{MPN_{t}}$$
$$mc_{t} = w_{t}-p_{t}-mpn_{t}$$
And after that use
$$MPN_{t} = (1-\alpha)\frac{Y_{t}}{N_{t}} = (1-\alpha)A_{t}N_{t}^{-\alpha}$$
also using $$N_{t} = \left(\frac{Y_{t}}{A_{t}}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}$$
Then you obtain the expression above.